# How to I replace specific values with text in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I'm trying to visualize the language skills of our students per program and over time. That would look something like this:

[image]

This is however not totally intuitive, so I would like to replace the y axis values so that:

```
> 20.0 codes for A, 
> 17.5 codes for B
> 15.0 codes for C
> 12.5 codes for D
> 10.0 codes for E.
```

I try to augment my original code and I write the following:

```
totdata%>%filter(program=="Ekonom")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=ADMISSIONROUND_ID,y=SVENSKA))+
geom_boxplot()**+
scale_y_continuous(labels=c("20.0" = "A","17.5" = "B", "15.0" = "C", "12.5"="D", "10"="E"))**
```

This produces the following graph, *which is the opposite of what I want*. The values has been replaced in the opposite order, so that the highest values is E rather than A.

[image]

Is there any way for me to preserve the original figure but replace my numbers with text values, as described above?

Small sample of data:

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585), class = "Date"), SVENSKA = c(15, 15, 15, 10, 15, 
15, 15, 10, 15, 20, 20, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 15, 20, 15, 10, 15, 
20, 10, 20, 15, 15, 10, 15, 10, 20, 10, 15, 15, NA, 15, 10, NA, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 20, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20), ADMISSIONROUND_ID = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("HT2012", "HT2013", "HT2014", "HT2015", "HT2016", 
"HT2017", "HT2018", "HT2019"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
    program = c("Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(
    start_date = structure(15585, class = "Date"), .rows = list(
        1:50)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep things dymanic by passing a function to the labels argument of `scale_y_continous()`, in this case reverse LETTERS of the length of the breaks:

```
df %>% 
  filter(program == "Ekonom") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ADMISSIONROUND_ID, y = SVENSKA)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) rev(LETTERS[seq_along(x)]))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the syntax. Are we creating a new function? Wouldn't we need curly brackets for that?

Comment: @Magnus - not in this case.  I've added a brief explanation.  Let me know if things still aren't clear.

Comment: Okay, but how does scale_y_continuous know that x signifies the length of the breaks and not ADMISSIONROUND_ID, as it does in the preceding function?

Comment: Because the default input of any function passed to the labels argument are the default breaks values.